# How do I compare a date to a number of conditions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to compare a date to a number of conditions and return a specific output based on the condition it meets. I don't like these `if` and `elsif` statements:

```
 def ugly_method
    if first_active_entitlement.try(:created_at) == nil
      "No timestamp on first active entitlement"
    elsif first_active_entitlement == nil
      "No Active Entitlement"
    elsif last_suspended_entitlement == nil 
      first_time_or_renewal(first_active_entitlement, start_date, end_date)
    elsif first_active_entitlement.try(:created_at) > last_suspended_entitlement.try(:suspended_at) && first_active_entitlement.try(:created_at) > start_date && first_active_entitlement.created_at < end_date
      "Restart"
    else
      first_time_or_renewal(first_active_entitlement, start_date, end_date)
  end
```

Has anyone ever had to compare a date to a number of different conditions? Anything obvious that would be easier that I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

I would break it down into multiple methods:

- Verify the `first_active_entitlement`
- verify the `last_suspended_entitlement`

These methods can return messages and maybe a flag to check the existence of the object.

Then, in your method, you can display the messages from these methods in case the method's flag is set to false, if not just execute renewal.

Comment: There's no need to thank us for clarifying. It's to help the community.